# Merging remote repo via git fetch into another repo

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, git-merge

Could really use some help here. I have created a repo and within that repo have done a subtree merge of different repos following these steps:

http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/subtree-merging-and-you/

So my structure looks like this:

```
 Parent Folder
      Component
         masterbranch 
      Tests  
         testapi
            masterbranch
         testnr 
            masterbranch
         testres
             masterbranch
```

Setting that up was no problem. But I am having difficulty adding the develop branch of each subtree. So with the structure above, I need the develop branch next to each master branch within the repo.

But this only works for one branch (master) because I am getting an git overlap error in the .bowerrc file and it says "can't bind" when I try to merge remote/develop following the steps in the link above.

I tried created a develop branch within Component and Tests and then merging in each remote repo (i.e. within the Component repo and newly created develop branch I did a git merge remote/develop.). But I'm getting merge conflicts for some reason when I do that..which I'm not sure why is happening.

What is the best way to go about merging the develop branch of remote into a develop branch within Component and Tests above??

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: FYI the `tree` command on *nix generates directory tree structures like the one you've included.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put both master and develop branches from a new remote repo into the same folder, git read-tree can’t do that, especially you have the same .bowerrc file in master and develop branches. git read-tree command will refuse to overwrite component entries that already existed in the original index file (remote/master).

So for your situation, you can use git submodules instead. It can put the remote branches into the same subfolder.

Comment: Well most of the files are the same between the master and develop, the only difference would be the written code for the actual components... So if I use the git read-tree command to set up my initial structure as I have above..I can't then create a new "develop" branch inside my "Component" repo, switch to that "develop" branch, and then do a "git merge remote-name/develop" to merge into that newly created develop branch? Why would that be giving me merge conflicts since its an empty "develop" branch? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can’t use git read-tree to add develop branch in the same folder with master branch. If you create a newly develop branch, actually it’s not an empty develop branch since you have created. You can switch to the new develop branch, you will find files in `Parent Folder`, `Component` and `Tests` folder still exist.